# Android Room retrieve autoGenerated ID and put in Child rows

Tags: android, android-room

I try to retrieve inserted "Group" and insert "Members" into the database. My idea is to get the Group with autoGenerated ID and set it as a foreign Key in the Members and insert them into Room database. Please post your examples and the idea how to resolve this problem.

Repo:  My idea is to retrieve it from AsyncTask but I dont know how to send result back to the method

```
public class GroupRepo{
private final GroupDao groupDao;
private final MemberDao memberDao;

public GroupRepo (Context context){
    DatabaseConfig db = DatabaseConfig.getDatabase(context);
    groupDao = db.groupDao();
    memberDao = db.memberDao();
}

public List<Group> getNonLiveGroup() {
    List<Group> result = null;
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Group>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Group> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            List<Group> m = null;
                m = groupDao.getGroup();
            return m;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Group> group){
        }
    }.execute();
    return null;
}
```

Member Entity:

```
 @Entity(tableName = "member",
    foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Group.class,
    parentColumns = "id",
    childColumns = "groupsId",
    onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Member {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int groupsId;

public void setGroupsId(int groupsId){
    this.groupsId = groupsId;
}
}
```

There may be other ways to do it and please show me with a brief example.

Answer (score 0):

In `groupDao`  when you insert a new group, make the method of adding return int. so it will return the added id.
for example

```
@Insert
int addNewGroup(Group Group)
```

and use the id that returned from the `addNewGroup` method when you add a new member.

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
             int id=  groupDao.insert(YOUR_GROUP_OBJECT);
             memberDao.insert(new Member(YOUR_NAME,id));
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void group){
            }
        }.execute();
```

Comment: then I think my problem is how to use AsyncTask to return the id. I try to create a call back to return the value to the method in my Repo. Could you provide a example for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I will present my approach how implemented this.

This are the Entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "groups", 
        indices = {@Index(value = {"id"}, unique = true)})
public class Group {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;

}


@Entity(tableName = "member",
        indices = {@Index(value = {"id"}, unique = true)},
        foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(
                entity = Group.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "groupId",
                onUpdate = CASCADE, onDelete = CASCADE)})
public class Member {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int groupId;

    public void setGroupId(int groupId){
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
}
```

When you already have your entities you have to create the Relationship between them. I do that with one additional class which extends `Group @Entity class` and holds list with members `List<Member>`.

```
public class GroupWithMembsers extends Group {

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "groupId", entity = Member.class)
    private List<Member> members;

    public List<Member> getMembers(){
        return this.members;
    }

}
```

Now, when you have all Groups and all Members you have to set the group id of all Members. And now you can insert all data into the Database like this:

```
@Dao
public abstract class GroupDao {

    @Transaction
    public void insertGroupWithMembsers(List<GroupWithMembsers> groupWithMembsers, RulesOfGolfDatabase database) {
        if (groupWithMembsers != null && database != null) {
            //First have to insert the entities which holds the @Relation
            insertGroups(groupWithMembsers);
            for (GroupWithMembsers group : groupWithMembsers) {
                //Now you can insert members, because thier foreignKeys (groupId) is already inserted into the Database
                database.memberDao().insertMembers(groupWithMembsers.getMembers());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you have any questions, just ask.
Hope I helped somehow :)